# Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? | Xcode suggestion does not work

Tags: swift2

I have the following Swift function

```
@IBAction func swapText(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let text = textView.text, let findText = findTextField.text,
      let replaceText = replaceTextField.text {
        textView.text =
          textView.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(findTextField.text,
            withString: replaceTextField.text, options: [], range: nil)
        findTextField.text = nil
        replaceTextField.text = nil
        view.endEditing(true)
        moveViewDown()
    }
}
```

`findTextField.text` and `replaceTextField.text` both give the warning:

> ```
> "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
> '!' or '?'?"
> ```

Using the Xcode suggested fix does not actually solve the issue.

I am fairly new to Swift so any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like above answer but actually if you not start with if-let you have to unwrapped value by insert '!' and the end of variable like this

```
if let text = textView.text, let findText = findTextField.text,
      let replaceText = replaceTextField.text {
        textView.text =
          textView!.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(findTextField!.text,
            withString: replaceTextField!.text, options: [], range: nil)
        findTextField.text = nil
        replaceTextField.text = nil
        view.endEditing(true)
        moveViewDown()
    }
```

You can also skip multiple let in if-let to.

```
if let text = textView.text, findText = findTextField.text, replaceText = replaceTextField.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already unwrapped these fields in your `if let` (as `findText` and `replaceText`), so you can just do

```
textView.text =
  text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(findText,
    withString: replaceText, options: [], range: nil)
```

Comment: Perfect. Works well.